# How to solve this best_estimator_ error caused by GridSearch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keyerror

I wanted to print RandomizedSearchCV's attribute best_estimator after fitting.
but got something wrong.
below is my main code:

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

parameters = {
    'min_child_weight':[2,3,4],
}

xlf = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,n_estimators=50,max_depth=5,min_child_weight = 1,
                     subsample=0.8,colsample_btree=0.8,objective='reg:linear',
                     scale_pos_weight=1,random_state=27)
n_iter_search = 5

gsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(xlf,param_distributions=parameters,n_iter=n_iter_search, cv=2, iid=False)


start=time.clock()
gsearch.fit(x_train.values,y_train.values,eval_set = [(x_test.values,y_test.values)],eval_metric = "rmse",
            early_stopping_rounds = 20)
end=time.clock()
print('RandomSearch Running time: %s Seconds'%(end-start))
print("Best score: %0.3f" % gsearch.best_score_)
best_estimator = gsearch.best_estimator_
print("Best parameters set",best_estimator)
```

and below is my error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonProject\TestPackagePytorch\code.py", line 213, in <module>
    print("Best parameters set",best_estimator)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 279, in __repr__
    repr_ = pp.pformat(self)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\pprint.py", line 144, in pformat
    self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\pprint.py", line 161, in _format
    rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\pprint.py", line 393, in _repr
    self._depth, level)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py", line 170, in format
    changed_only=self._changed_only)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py", line 414, in _safe_repr
    params = _changed_params(object)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_pprint.py", line 98, in _changed_params
    if (repr(v) != repr(init_params[k]) and
KeyError: 'base_score'
```

And in the process of traing,there is one sentence appears:

```
  This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
  passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
  verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.
```

I have tried also by GridSearchCV  but failed and get the same error information.
Please help me!
Also,I had tried to chance other datasets and get the same error information.

Comment: This looks like a bug in either Scikit-Learn or XGBoost. I would file a bug report with Scikit-Learn. Make sure to carefully follow the bug reporting instructions.

Comment: Any progress in this issue? could you solve it? @https://stackoverflow.com/users/13575116/%e4%bd%99%e4%b9%9d%e5%a4%a9

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the `sklearn` version, if you are using older version of `sklearn` kindly upgrade it by using the below command for anaconda.

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.23.1
```

I tried your code with the sample model, I was able to get result, I'm using sklearn version 0.22.2.

Below is the sample output of your code for my data which is having base_score in it.

```
RandomSearch Running time: 4.218714999999975 Seconds
Best score: 0.789
Best parameters set XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_btree=0.8,
             colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1,
             gamma=0, importance_type='gain', learning_rate=0.1,
             max_delta_step=0, max_depth=5, min_child_weight=4, missing=None,
             n_estimators=50, n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='reg:linear',
             random_state=27, reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
             seed=None, silent=None, subsample=0.8, verbosity=1)
```